# Sum negative and positive values separately

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, sum

I am attempting to sum up positive and negative values separately in XSL v1.0.

I have XML like this:

```
<Billing_Statements>
    <Statement_Details>
        <Invoice_Details>
            <Meter_Details>
                <Consumption>XX</Consumption>
            </Meter_Details>
            <Meter_Details>
                <Consumption>XX</Consumption>
            </Meter_Details>
        </Invoice_Details>
        <Invoice_Details>
            <Meter_Details>
                <Consumption>XX</Consumption>
            </Meter_Details>
            <Meter_Details>
                <Consumption>XX</Consumption>
            </Meter_Details>
        </Invoice_Details>
    </Statement_Details>
</Billing_Statements>
```

Where XX can be a positive or a negative value.

I need to output first the sum of the positive values and then the sum of the negative values for all Invoice_Detail nodes for each Statement_Details.

At the moment I have tried:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(Invoice_Details/Meter_Details[Consumption &lt; 0])" />
```

and many variations of this and they all return a sum of `0` no matter what.

When collecting all the other information from the Meter_Details nodes my for-each section works perfectly as this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Invoice_Details/Meter_Details[Consumption &lt; 0]">
```

And selects only nodes with negative or positive values. Why does this not work for the sum()?

I'm certainly struggling with XSL here and would love any help I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use**:

```
sum(*/*/*[. >=0])
```

**and**

```
sum(*/*/*[not(. >=0)])
```

**Here is a complete transformation that uses these two relative XPath expressions:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="Statement_Details">

Statement <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Invoice_Details">
  Invoice <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
    Positive: <xsl:value-of select="sum(*/*[. >=0])"/>
    Negative: <xsl:value-of select="sum(*/*[not(. >=0)])"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (having the wanted structure):

```
<Billing_Statements>
    <Statement_Details>
        <Invoice_Details>
            <Meter_Details>
                <Consumption>-3</Consumption>
            </Meter_Details>
            <Meter_Details>
                <Consumption>5</Consumption>
            </Meter_Details>
        </Invoice_Details>
        <Invoice_Details>
            <Meter_Details>
                <Consumption>8</Consumption>
            </Meter_Details>
            <Meter_Details>
                <Consumption>-12</Consumption>
            </Meter_Details>
        </Invoice_Details>
        <Invoice_Details>
            <Meter_Details>
                <Consumption>22</Consumption>
            </Meter_Details>
            <Meter_Details>
                <Consumption>3</Consumption>
            </Meter_Details>
        </Invoice_Details>
        <Invoice_Details>
            <Meter_Details>
                <Consumption>4</Consumption>
            </Meter_Details>
            <Meter_Details>
                <Consumption>-5</Consumption>
            </Meter_Details>
        </Invoice_Details>
    </Statement_Details>
    <Statement_Details>
        <Invoice_Details>
            <Meter_Details>
                <Consumption>-13</Consumption>
            </Meter_Details>
            <Meter_Details>
                <Consumption>25</Consumption>
            </Meter_Details>
        </Invoice_Details>
        <Invoice_Details>
            <Meter_Details>
                <Consumption>77</Consumption>
            </Meter_Details>
            <Meter_Details>
                <Consumption>-15</Consumption>
            </Meter_Details>
        </Invoice_Details>
        <Invoice_Details>
            <Meter_Details>
                <Consumption>31</Consumption>
            </Meter_Details>
            <Meter_Details>
                <Consumption>-3</Consumption>
            </Meter_Details>
        </Invoice_Details>
        <Invoice_Details>
            <Meter_Details>
                <Consumption>-87</Consumption>
            </Meter_Details>
            <Meter_Details>
                <Consumption>54</Consumption>
            </Meter_Details>
        </Invoice_Details>
    </Statement_Details>
</Billing_Statements>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
Statement 1
  Invoice 1
    Positive: 5
    Negative: -3
  Invoice 2
    Positive: 8
    Negative: -12
  Invoice 3
    Positive: 25
    Negative: 0
  Invoice 4
    Positive: 4
    Negative: -5

Statement 2
  Invoice 1
    Positive: 25
    Negative: -13
  Invoice 2
    Positive: 77
    Negative: -15
  Invoice 3
    Positive: 31
    Negative: -3
  Invoice 4
    Positive: 54
    Negative: -87
```

Comment: Thanks!
Although that sums ALL instances at that level it lead me to:

Comment: Thanks!
There's a lot more going in my project but using:
`sum(../Meter_Details/Consumption[not(. >=0)])`
Seems to work for me.